# Modular Java Application on GIT repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, branch, git-submodules

I'm working on a "modular Java application", it has around 60 independent modules, all obviously "buildable" on their own.

I'm trying to understand what can be the best approach to structure this type of application under GIT.

I'll explain better myself:

I've been working several years with SVN and it would be really easy for me to structure a project like this under a centralized version control tool such as SVN, while I'm not sure about the GIT best practices and pros/cons.

**With SVN:**

I would import all the project under the same repository

I would consider two different approaches, with similar consequences, for example:

```
 mod_A
   |___trunk
   |___branches
   |   |___branch_A
   |
   |___tags
 mod_B
   |___trunk
   |___branches
   |   |___branch_A
   |   |___branch_B
   |
   |___tags
```

OR

```
 trunk
   |___mod_a
   |___mod_b
   |___mod_c
 branches
   |___branch_A
   |   |___mod_a
   |___branch_B
       |___mod_a
       |___mod_b
```

With both the approaches it would be really easy for me to achieve information like, which are the modules branched for a particular feature, and see the application from the modules prospective but also from the branches prospective.

Moreover, with both the structures I would be able to easily branch just some of the modules without being forced to branch them all anytime.

**With GIT:**

At the moment the modular application i'm working with is structured with a single independent repo for any module, in my view this structure, even if brings some advantages, has also a real big issue.

In fact it looks hard for me to have a clear whole overview of the application, cause I've to connect to every single repository and check the branches to understand which modules are involved in a particular branch, so if I've to manage a branched version of my application, that for example involves just 7 modules to be branched in a particular BUG_FIXING or FEATURE branch and not the whole application, I would have no way to get this info through GIT, and I should manage this information in a custom way.

Then even if the application would have been set up within the same repo, i would have been unable to decide to branch just a subset of modules cause "Git operates on the entire repository, not on individual directories".

Can you please clarify how can be the best approach to follow with a modular application, can GIT sub modules be a solution? Is there any other approach i'm not considering, or i'm moving from wrong assumptions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should manage the module Java application in **one git repo** as you managed in one SVN repo, since all the modules are works for the same project.

For the branching module structure for you application, I will suggest **manage each module in separate branches(`modX`), and manage your entire project  in `master` branch**.

The work flow can be:

- Manage the project level files in `master` branch. the structure for master branch as:

  ```
  Root (master branch)
     |___... (project level files)
  ```
- Checkout module branches  (such as `modA` branch, `modB` branch and `modC` branch) from master. Deleted the project level files and add files for module in `mod_X` folder.

  Such as for branch modA, the structure is:

  ```
  Root (modA branch)
     |___mod_A (folder)
             |___... (module A level files)
  ```
- When you finished work for module X, then merge `modX` branch into `master` branch.
- After all the modules are finished work (and merged into `master`), the file structure for `master` branch should be:

  ```
  Root (master branch)
     |___... (project level files)
     |___mod_A (folder)
             |___... (module A level files)
     |___mod_B (folder)
             |___... (module B level files)
     |___mod_C (folder)
             |___... (module C level files)
  ```
- If you update module X in `modX` branch, then merge `modX` branch again into `master` branch to make sure the application is updated.
- To maintain project-level (application aggregator) files, you can also develop/test/fixbug on `develop`, `feature` and `hotfix` branches:

  1. `master` branch as the production version for your java application.
  2. `develop` branch (long living branch which should checkout from `master` branch) is used for all the developers work on it. When the changed application is build successful (verified), you can merge `develop` branch into `master`.
  3. `feature`branches are short living branches. If you need to develop new features for your application, you can checkout a feature branch from `develop` branch. And then the feature is finished, merge feature branch into `develop` branch to verify your code.
  4. `hotfix` branches are also short living branches. You can fix bugs on the branches, when the bug(s) is fixed, merge the hotfix branch into `develop` branch.

  And there has [a successful branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you can refer for managing the project-level (application aggregator) files.

Comment: That's a very nice explanation Marina! But it comes in my mind a doubt: with this structure i would have just a single entry point of view for the entire project, one single whole project aggregator, which is the master, what if want to maintain more code-lines that can be made by a mix of branched modules and standard ones. For example if I want to keep the feature_a on it, I would merge mod_a_feat_branch_a, mod_b, mod_c_feature_branch_a and so on on the master but what if i want to maintain more application aggregator and not just a single one.

Comment: I added the part to manage  project level files (application aggregator) in the end my answer answer. And yes, the entire project usually not only managed on `master` branch but also managed in `develop`, `feature` and `hotfix` branches etc.

Comment: Thanks Marina, looks really consistent and reasonable! Would like to have one last feedback from you: in case the whole application is huge in terms of space consumption, is there anyway to manage the thing that you have to download the whole repo containing the whole project anytime? Why if a developer have to work on a single module, it has to download locally the 59 rest of the modules, i know that GIT works like this, and it makes this as one of its biggest benefit (you will never lose any if the server crashes cause you have all you need locally) but it looks a bit extreme to me...

Comment: You can  clone a single branch such as  `git clone URL --single-branch modA --branch modA`. But I will recommend to clone the whole repo for the two reasons: 1. The developer can not always work on a single branch; 2. clone all branches won't consume far larger speac than clone a single branch, since the working directory is unique. Such as if the current HEAD is point to modA branch, the working directory only show the files for `modA` branch, files on other branches and versions are stored in `.git/objects` folder https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects.

Comment: Marina i'm keeping studying your idea,again it looks nice,but again i got doubts and i hope so much you will keep being so gentle answerng me.Why crate different branchs for every different mods and duplicate them in the proj-level(app aggregators),what are the benefts instead keeping them just in proj-level and for example working on them in the dev branch?I guess it allows you to merge/tag a single mod without necessarily merge/tag the others,moreover easier to cherry pick a single mod change,am i saying right?what else?I'm going to sell this approach so I really need to understand it deeply

Comment: And mostly... how to run a merge from a specific mod branch, let's say mod_a branch --> mod_A (folder)  to a mod_a sub folder of dev or master branches, the three are aligned, but won't GIT ask for the remotion of the other modules? the ones that exist under Master but not exists under the mod_a branches, how would you run the merge command in this case?

Comment: Yeah, correct. And another reason to manage modules in separate branches is to keep the modules easy traceable. You can switch to a certain version of a module easily. But if you are not frequently update modules, it's also ok to update modules in develop branch. It's depend on your own situation, and you can make changes for the branching module based on your situation.

Comment: For module branches, you should manage modules in a certain folder. As the second structure in my answer, files of module A are managed in `mod_A` folder of `modA` branch. So when you merge `modA` branch into `master`, it will add/update the `mod_A` folder in `master` branch and won't disturb other folders or the root directory of the `master` branch.

Comment: I have to make you a statue :)

Answer (score 1):

Aside: Do not use branches to manage different modules. Branches are to be short lived and ultimately merged back to master when ready for release.

---

If the modules "change/release" together, you could lean towards keeping them in one repo. Though the fact that each module had its own trunk/branches folders in SVN seems to indicate they change separately.

If you're using maven with your java application, it could be setup in one repo as a multi-module project.

If you go with separate repos, you can name your branches similarly (add a ticket number or such like `feature/ticket-123-more-cow-bells`) so you know a given feature impacts multiple modules/repos.

If you go with separate repos per module, then you could use git sub-modules to glue them back together but that's more of a workaround.

Perhaps also [reading about a few different git branching strategies](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) would help you understand how 'git thinks' about branches.

Comment: Mmmhh... as per nature of a modular application, modules should be changed/released separately, in the first version of my application i can have mod_a-1.0, mod_b-1.0, mod_c-1.0 and then in my second release just an update to mod_b-1.1 while the other version will be the ones released in my first release (1.0). I understand your feedback about the separate repos, but i still find it a bad idea because it will make all the modules unrelated by them.. even if releasable separately they are part of the same application, and using different repository does not give me any chance to relate them.

Comment: That article is a good one, I already studied it, but honestly it does not give me any help finding best practices to follow in order to structure a modular Java application. Thanks for the reference anyway

Comment: Sometimes I modularize my java apps just to have a separation of concerns for a given module but in practice all the modules change together meaning every feature changes every module. For those types of project, I prefer to keep them in one repo and use a maven multi-module project.